# Finding a basis for eigenspace problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find the basis of the eigenspace for the matrix A for the eigenvalue of 4

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 3\\
         3 & 1 &-3\\
        -3 & 3&  7\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So I subtracted 4 from the diagonals to get

$$  \begin{bmatrix}     -3 & 3 & 3\\
         3 &-3 &-3\\
        -3&  3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using the third row to clear the other rows I get

$$\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0 & 0\\
       0 & 0 & 0\\
       -3 & 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Which would get $[1 \:\:\: -1 \:\:\: -1]$ for the last row. (after dividing it by -3)
So $X_1 - X_2 - X_3 = 0$ thus $X_1 = X_2 + X_3$ and we get

$$X_2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } X_3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So the eigenvectors and basis should be 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} ,  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

However I get back the answer

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} ,  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

on my math program.

Can someone explain to me where I went wrong? I managed to answer other exercises just fine, but I seem to be getting more and more of these exercises where I get slightly different answers than those that I have found.

Comment: We should note the eigenvalue of 4 has multiplicity 2, and that seems to be why there are 2 eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are both correct.  The eigenspace is a plane, and a basis is any two vectors in that plane that are linearly independent.

Comment: So the same applies to when I, for example, get the eigenvector [-2,1] and the actual solution given would be [2,-1], these would both be correct?

Comment: Yes, they would both be correct.